# Share history in multiple zsh shell

Tags: zsh

I am trying to setup `zsh` so that it shares command history between different `zsh` sessions:

- in multiple tabs
- in multiple gnome-terminals
- in different `screen` sessions

I have put this in `.zshrc`

```
#To save every command before it is executed (this is different from bash's history -a solution):
setopt inc_append_history

#To retrieve the history file everytime history is called upon.
setopt share_history
```

but that does not work.

e.g. I type 1 command: `gedit afile`
and then I go to and zsh and type `history`. I don't see `gedit afile`.

output of 'setopt' is

```
 % setopt
nohistbeep
histexpiredupsfirst
histfindnodups
histignorealldups
histignoredups
histignorespace
histnostore
histreduceblanks
histsavenodups
histverify
incappendhistory
interactive
monitor
promptsubst
sharehistory
shinstdin
zle
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the output if you run `setopt`?

Comment: see also similar Q&A http://superuser.com/questions/446594/separate-up-arrow-lookback-for-local-and-global-zsh-history

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669971/zsh-can-i-have-a-combined-history-for-all-of-my-shells

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is *you need to set `share_history`*, you do that with:

`setopt share_history`

Since you obviously did that already (and that option actually works). I suggest you to check:

- whether *both* shells have the option set;
- whether you are not typing commands with a leading space (since `histignorespace` makes those be ignored)
- Do you have `$HISTFILE` set to the same value in all shells?
- whether you are actually saving any history? Say, if you issue `echo 123` in tab-1. Go to tab-2, call `history`. Is it there? (as per your problem, not). Now issue, `fc -R` (means re-read the history file), and then `history` is it there now? If not, you may also want to call `fc -A` (`-A` will forcefully append your history the file) at tab-1 to make sure history is written to the file.

Comment: To retrieve the history file [every time history is called upon](http://askubuntu.com/a/23631/42522), `setopt share_history`

Comment: I appreciate the steps you added to help with debugging. Somehow my `~/.zsh_history` was set so that only root could write to it, which was why commands weren't being appended properly. This finally helped me get to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 14):

try searching *after* pressing `enter`.

---

what i tested was:

- open 2 zsh shells
- go to zsh shell 1 and execute `echo "something"`
- go to zsh shell 2, press `enter`, then check if you see the command from shell 1.

in my case i will **not** see the command until i press `enter` in the tab i am searching in.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. The accepted answer wasn't helpful in my case.

Comment: This was my problem too. You should try to highlight that you need to press `enter` _in the tab you're searching in_. I had first read your answer as "press enter after the command".

Answer (score 1):

The problem might have been that you shouldn't set `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` if you're using `SHARE_HISTORY` - mentioned in the [zsh options docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html) (search for "SHARE_HISTORY").

> ...also causes your typed commands to be appended to the history file (the latter is like specifying INC_APPEND_HISTORY, which should be turned off if this option is in effect).

`INC_APPEND_HISTORY` is used to share history between shells, while allowing you more control about when new history commands get imported. A nice tip from the same docs:

> If you find that you want more control over when commands get imported, you may wish to turn SHARE_HISTORY off, INC_APPEND_HISTORY or INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME (see above) on, and then manually import commands whenever you need them using ‘fc -RI’.