# How to save command history in all shell

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using Zsh with 'oh-my-zsh' with iTerm2 on macoxs.
I find that when I execute 'history', it only list the command of my current tab.
How can I save the history

- among all the tabs in iTerm
- even when I exit iTerms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share history in multiple zsh shell](https://superuser.com/questions/519596/share-history-in-multiple-zsh-shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```bsh
setopt share_history
```

Documentation here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-share-history

Answer (score -1):

install this plugin on your zsh

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdharma/zinit/master/doc/install.sh)"
```

then, in your .zshrc file, paste these commands at the end of the file

```
zinit light zdharma/fast-syntax-highlighting
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-completions
```