# ZSH: how to call ZLE widgets directly?

Tags: zsh

The documentation says in section [18.4 Widgets](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zle-Widgets), that a "widget’s job is simply to perform some small action". But I cannot find a general description how to invoke these actions, i.e. how to call a widget.

I've seen in examples (for example see [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/446594/separate-up-arrow-lookback-for-local-and-global-zsh-history)) that widgets can bin bound to keys using `bindkey KEY WIDGET`. Then one can call the widget using `KEY`.

I wanted to toggle `set-local-history` and I tried:

```
$ zle set-local-history 1
zle: widgets can only be called when ZLE is active
```

`zle -h` not work, but I've found [a description of the arguments here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zle-Builtins). But it does not seem there is something like `--call`.

What am I doing wrong? How is it possible to call the widget without bindkey? How can I print the current status? (`set-local-history` toggles the state)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can execute widget by the widget `execute-named-cmd`, which is bound to `ESC-x` (emacs bindings) or `:` (vi bindings):

> `execute-named-cmd (ESC-x) (:) (unbound)`
>
> Read the name of an editor command and execute it.

This opens up a *mini-buffer* below the command line, where you can start zle widgets. (Autocompletion is available!):

```
$ [ESC-x]
execute: set-[TAB]
set-local-history  set-mark-command
```

To query the state of `zle` (including local history), use the variable `$ZLE_STATE` (only accessible inside widget functions):

> ```
> ZLE_STATE (scalar)
> ```
>
> Contains a set of space-separated words that describe the current zle state.
>
> Currently,  the  states  shown are the insert mode as set by the overwrite-mode or vi-replace widgets and whether history
>   commands will visit imported entries as controlled by the set-local-history widget.   The  string  contains  `insert`  if
>   characters  to  be  inserted on the command line move existing characters to the right or `overwrite` if characters to be
>    inserted overwrite existing characters. **It contains `localhistory` if only local history  commands  will  be  visited  or
>   `globalhistory` if imported history commands will also be visited.**
>
> The substrings are sorted in alphabetical order so that if you want to test for two specific substrings in a future-proof
>   way, you can do match by doing:
>
> ```
> if [[ $ZLE_STATE == *globalhistory*insert* ]]; then ...; fi
> ```

*All quotes from `man zshzle`.*

Comment: Uh yes, I think I have seen both quotes already, but I did not understand the value in the three braces. The man page says: "These special parameters are always available in widget functions, but are not in any way special  outside ZLE." That means, to get ZLE_STATE, I need to define a function and a custom widget, right?

Comment: @lumbric : You're right, `ZLE_STATE` is defined only inside widget functions. I refined my answer. What is your goal? [Wild guess: To indicate local/global history in my prompt I use a widget to (i.) set an shell variable (this is possible inside widgets) and (ii.) execute `zle set-local-history`.]

Comment: My primary goal was to understand the concept of zle widgets. Playing around with set-local-history, I wanted to know if it is currently set to global or local. I thought there must be a we to get the current status (similar to calling "setopt" to get the currently enabled options). My original goal was solved already in [this Q&A](http://superuser.com/questions/446594/separate-up-arrow-lookback-for-local-and-global-zsh-history).

Comment: I would expect the string in the if test should be "`*globalhistory*insert*`" instead of "`*insert*globalhistory*`", based on reading the sentence before the example?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: A very good point, thanks! I checked with the source code and tried the given example myself, concluding that the example in the man page is wrong, not the statement ("sorted alphabetically"). I edited my answer and will send a path to the _zsh-workers_ mailing list.

Comment: Does anyone know why you can't call widgets directly without some key binding? Seems rather arbitrary to me and took me a while to accept it until I found this response.

Comment: @dedeibel: This is possbile with the zle-widget `execute-named-cmd`, which is bound to `ALT-x` when using emacs bindings.

Comment: Thanks @mpy but I'll count this as key-binding. I don't understand why someone just can't type "my-widget-function".

Comment: @dedeibel: Because the widget can act on the current command line. -- Why do you need a widget, isn't a normal shell dunction suitable? It would be best if you describe you particular use-case _in a new question_.

Comment: @mpy There is no real use case. I just spent a lot of time to realize it was not possible and I still don't understand that limitation. Seems arbitrary. Hoped for a technical explanation - could not find something in the docs. Sorry if I caused confusion and long discussion.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `tmux` you can call the bound key with `send-keys`.

Examples:

```
# Current pane
$ tmux send-keys C-r

# Some targeted pane
$ tmux send-keys -t SESSION_NAME:WINDOW_NUMBER.PANE_NUMBER C-z
```