# How to set-local-history on zsh startup?

Tags: zsh

Calling `zle set-local-history 1` from `.zshrc` causes

```
widgets can only be called when ZLE is active
```

Is there a way to execute the widget on startup, <del>or maybe a setting for this particular case</del>?

---

upd: I checked zsh source code, and I believe that `hist_skip_flags` is [set](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/32cceefa95903190829af26723b7ad51c163040c/Src/Zle/zle_hist.c#L782) only by `set-local-history` widget, so there is no setting to change this behavior. However it is much harder to determinate if it's possible to run zle widget on startup.

Comment: "The zsh line editor is usually abbreviated to `zle'. Normally it fires itself up for any interative shell; you don't have to do anything special until you decide you need to change its behaviour. If everything looks OK and you're not interested in how zle is started up, skip to the next subsection. " please read [A User's Guide to the Z-Shell](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide04.html) for more info

Comment: @DavidPostill, could you expand on your point? Are you implying that the the problem is that zle not loaded during execution of zshrc? I don't think so, because `bindkey` can be used in zshrc, which according to the guide should mean that zle is loaded.

Comment: See [Separate up arrow lookback for local and global ZSH history - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/446594/separate-up-arrow-lookback-for-local-and-global-zsh-history) for the correct usage of `set-local-history 1`

Comment: @DavidPostill, I've seen this and some other related answers, they don't answer my question about changing the initial state. It is easy to show that `ZLE_STATE` is persisting in between widget calls and is global (changes to it are visible to other widgets), so it is possible to switch between local and global history at runtime without wrapping and rebinding all functions that access history.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert on this and have no more advice. Hopefully someone else will be able to help.

Comment: What is your goal? Your question might be a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)?!

Comment: @mpy, I'm experimenting right now and want to switch between local and global history at will, but having global history by default is too disruptive for me.

Comment: You can get a zle-command prompt with the default keybinding `ALT+X`, where you can execute `set-local-history` which will toggle between global and local history. If you want to have the local state by default, IMHO you have to redefine the widgets you are using to access the history, as it is explained in the Q&A which DavidPostill linked above.

Comment: Does setting it in a `zle-line-init` hook work for you?

Comment: @okapi, kind of. It is executed before each user input request. To achieve what I want I have to use an environment variable to set local history only on the first execution of the widget. But I like this solution more than rebinding every function that touches history.

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on [the comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1768812/how-to-set-local-history-on-zsh-startup?noredirect=1#comment2766462_1768812) by @okapi:

```
zle-line-init() {
  if [[ "$ZLE_LOCAL_HISTORY_SET" != "1" ]]; then
    ZLE_LOCAL_HISTORY_SET=1
    zle set-local-history 1
  fi
}
zle -N zle-line-init
```

`zle-line-init` executed on every user input request, so additional environment variable required to set local history only on the first run.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.